# React ES6 Scope of Function Declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've looked around for several days and cannot seem to solve this. I have a form that handles a file upload via an XMLHTTPRequestUpload, I have an onProgress callback that I would like to call and update visually what's happening in the UI, but I can't seem to make any successful function calls from inside "onProgress".

I tried to use console.log to find the scope in which my function updateProgress is defined. 'this' inside of the uploadFile, onProgress call is the XMLHTTP request itself. So I tried it for 'AddShow', the class itself. It doesn't report an error, and lists that updateProgress is a member function of the class, but when trying to call it, I still get

```
AddShow.updateProgress is not a function
    at XMLHttpRequestUpload.onProgress
```

So where's waldo? How do I call my function?

Here's my entire React Component Class:

```
export class AddShow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleTextChange = this.handleTextChange.bind(this);
    this.uploadFile = this.uploadFile.bind(this);
    this.updateProgress = this.updateProgress.bind(this);
  }

  // function that updates the state of the form input
  handleTextChange(evt) {
    this.props.dispatch(actions.changeShowTitleText(evt.target.value));
  }

  //function that show the progress of file upload
  updateProgress(progress) {
    progress = Math.floor(progress * 100);
    //call the dispatch actions to update redux state
    this.props.dispatch(actions.changeCompleteValue(progress));
    this.props.dispatch(actions.changeCompleteText(progress + '%'));
    this.props.dispatch(actions.changeCompleteARIA(progress + ' percent'));

    // this.props.complete = progress;
    // this.props.completeText = progress + '%';
    // this.props.ariaCompleteText = progress + ' percent';
  }

  // when 'add show' is pressed, validate form and upload
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let titleText = this.props.showTitle;
    if (titleText < 1) {
      alert("Please provide a Show Title.");
    } else {
      // a title has been typed in, call upload with that info.
      this.uploadFile(titleText);
    }
  }

  //function that finally uploads the file given all the information
  uploadFile(title) {
    var uploader = new VimeoUpload({
      name: title,
      file: selectedFile,
      token: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN,
      onProgress: function(data) {
        var percent = data.loaded / data.total;
        AddShow.updateProgress(percent);
      },
      onComplete: function(videoId, index) {
        var url = 'https://vimeo.com/' + videoId
      }
    });

    uploader.upload();
  }

  // set the global file variable if the input changes
  handleFileSelect(file) {
    console.log("These are the files retrieved", file.target.files[0]);
    selectedFile = file.target.files[0];
  }

  render() {
    var {dispatch, showTitle, complete, completeText, ariaCompleteText} = this.props;
    completeText = '0%';
    ariaCompleteText = "0 percent";

    return(
      <div className="row">
        <div className="column small-centered small-11 medium-8 large-6">
          <div className="container">
            <p>Drag the Video You Want to Upload to Screen</p>
            <form ref="form" onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)} className="add-show-form">
              <input type="file" placeholder="Select Video File" onChange={(evt) => this.handleFileSelect(evt)}/>
              <p ref="alertText"></p>
              <input type="text" value={this.props.showTitle} onChange={this.handleTextChange} placeholder="Show Title"/>
              <button className="button expanded">Add Show</button>
            </form>
            <div className="progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuetext={this.props.ariaCompleteText} aria-valuemax="100">
              <span className="progress-meter" style={{width: this.props.complete + '%'}}>
                <p className="progress-meter-text">{this.props.completeText}</p>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: hmm Try this, change your anonymous method to an arrow function to bind the instance by using `onProgress: (data) => {` and change `AddShow.updateProgress(percent);` to `this.updateProgress(percent);` Then please comment on what error you get, if any.

Comment: `AddShow.updateProgress` cannot work because `updateProgress` is method of an **instance** of `AddShow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to maintain a reference to the outer scope (i.e. the outer this) within the new scope of the onProgress callback.  The traditional (ES5) way to approach this was to create a reference to it within a variable (typically named self), then use that to call the method within the callback:

```
  uploadFile(title) {
    // self now references the outer this
    var self = this;
    var uploader = new VimeoUpload({
      name: title,
      file: selectedFile,
      token: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN,
      onProgress: function(data) {
        var percent = data.loaded / data.total;

        // we can access the outer scope on self here
        self.updateProgress(percent);
      },
      onComplete: function(videoId, index) {
        var url = 'https://vimeo.com/' + videoId
      }
    });

    uploader.upload();
  }
```

Given that you are using classes in your code, I would assume you are happy to use ES6 code, so the more elegant way to achieve the same effect is to use a lambda (or fat-arrow) function.  This means declaring your functions with this syntax:

```
const someFunction = (anArgument) => {
    return aResult;
}
```

Which is (roughly) equivalent to:

```
function someFunction(anArgument) {
    return aResult;
}
```

The difference is that when you declare a function with lambda syntax, a new scope is not created.  Effectively, the `this` inside the function is the same as the `this` outside it.  We can then write the uploadFile handler as:

```
  uploadFile(title) {
    var uploader = new VimeoUpload({
      name: title,
      file: selectedFile,
      token: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN,
      onProgress: (data) => {
        var percent = data.loaded / data.total;
        this.updateProgress(percent);
      },
      onComplete: (videoId, index) => {
        var url = 'https://vimeo.com/' + videoId
      }
    });

    uploader.upload();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I was translating from the older syntax to the new ES6 one to closer match the documentation and I guess I missed that.

Comment: *"The difference is that when you declare a function with lambda syntax, a new scope is not created."* That's not correct. `this` is not the same as scope. Every function call creates a new scope. However in the case of an arrow function, the scope doesn't have its own `this` value.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for you is to just use an arrow function which has lexical scoping and will be scoped to the context of `uploadFile`:

```
uploadFile(title) {
  var uploader = new VimeoUpload({
    // ...
    onProgress: (data) => { // <-- use arrow function
      var percent = data.loaded / data.total;
      this.updateProgress(percent);
    }
  // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can save the context in a variable and use that:

```
uploadFile(title) {
  var context = this; // save context
  var uploader = new VimeoUpload({
    // ...
    onProgress: function(data) {
      var percent = data.loaded / data.total;
      context.updateProgress(percent); // use context
    }
  // ...
}
```

---

Do note that this line

```
AddShow.updateProgress(percent);
```

attempts to access `updateProgress` on the function itself, not the prototype, which doesn't have this method.

If you wanted to call the function in a static manner like this, you'd need to call it on the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Use static method

```js
static updateProgress(progress) {
    progress = Math.floor(progress * 100);
    //call the dispatch actions to update redux state
    this.props.dispatch(actions.changeCompleteValue(progress));
    this.props.dispatch(actions.changeCompleteText(progress + '%'));
    this.props.dispatch(actions.changeCompleteARIA(progress + ' percent'));
}
```

Solution 2: Use arrow function in uploadFile method

```js
uploadFile(title) {
  var uploader = new VimeoUpload({
    name: title,
    file: selectedFile,
    token: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN,
    onProgress: function(data) => {
      var percent = data.loaded / data.total;
      // this now refers to your AddShow component
      this.updateProgress(percent);
    },
    onComplete: function(videoId, index) {
      var url = 'https://vimeo.com/' + videoId
    }
  });

  uploader.upload();
}
```

You cannot call `addShow` method directly from the Class as it is not a `static` method. To solve this issue I would suggest you either add a `static` keyword in your method so that you can invoke it from the the class directly without having to instantiate it or by using an arrow function in your uploadFile method.